# Android application logical classes: service, handler, ...?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, class, android-intent

I've been trying to find a simple and clear solution for my question in the last 2 hours. Hope someone can help me here.

I'm developing my first *real* android application. So of course I want to separate my activities (UI) from the application logic and have a nice structured package tree. But after some research I'm a little bit confused, what is the right choice for my background objects that do not need an user interface: *normal* java class, services, threads, handler..?

What I want to do:

I want the create an Object whose methods can be called by the activity. These methods on the other hand should call some Tasks (e.g. check for update on server or create a new message and send it to server).

I thought something about this:

3rd Layer: User Interface (probably activities, right?)

2nd Layer: **Some Objects** that will handle the user inputs and call:

1st Layer Background Tasks e.g. downloading stuff,  (I thought about ASyncTasks)

First of all I thought that those objects from second layershould be services. But there is no need to run a process for a long time doing permanently stuff in my application. Then I considered normal java classes, but I think this would be too easy. Handler?

Hope my question is clear enough! Maybe my basic concept is already wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are two basic rules for writing efficient code:
>
> - Don't do work that you don't need to do.
> - Don't allocate memory if you can avoid it.

Actually, thinking for two hours is a bit not enough, but...

First of all, I'd like to suggest you reading [Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html), so that you could think of performance on the stage of design, and not when all is complete and should be re-written to make it beautiful.

The first tip in that article is: avoid creating unnecessary objects. While OOP is cool with all that object orientedness, it's not that great for mobile devices with limited resources. It's better not to create too many layers.

Talking about Services, AsyncTasks and the rest: they are not a layer. They come in parallel. But if you want, for example, an AsyncTask for downloading data, which will be used in different activities, you should implement it in a separate class for sure. You will be able to access the code from different places and avoid [memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) (for example, during screen rotation or other configuration changes).

Sometimes different activities (or fragments) should use the same pieces of code. In this situation I'd create a base Activity class and extend all my activities from that class rather than from the default `android.app.Activity`.

This is for the beginning. But from my own experience I can say, that no matter how much you think about it or read, you won't create a masterpiece on the first attempt. All comes with experience. Ideas which seemed great on paper may become unapplicable or inefficient when you implemented them. Some people study and improve, others not. Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your reply! never thought about this topic from this angle. In school they tell us to use OOP to the fullest. So did I get this straight. I should write the logic of my app also in the activities?

Comment: Just try to keep in activities everything related to that activity, especially methods requiring activity `Context`. But it doesn't mean you cannot subclass or whatever. Just do it reasonably